# Re-structuring data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VB scripting and seek for help in restructuring data in following format.

Data is in the format below

```
ID      Dt        Var1      value1            Var2          Value2
234456  3/14/2017               
234456           problem    tap leakage       Manufacturer  abc org
234456           defect     LEAKAGE           Supplier      xyz org
234456           remedy     repaired        
234456           defct_dt   3/14/2017       
234456           rdy_dt     3/17/2017       
234457  3/21/2017               
234457           problem    tap leakage       Manufacturer  edc org
234457           problem    motor problem       
234457           defect     LEAKAGE     
234457           defect     DEFECTIVE         Supplier      123 org
234457           remedy     repaired        
234457           defct_dt   3/21/2017
```

Desired output

```
ID  Dt  problem1    Problem2    defect1 defect2 remedy1 remedy2 defect_dt   remedy_dt   Manufacturer    Supplier

234456  3/14/2017   tap leakage     LEAKAGE     repaired        3/14/2017   3/17/2017   abc org xyz org

234457  3/21/2017   tap leakage motor problem   LEAKAGE DEFECTIVE   repaired        3/21/2017   3/25/2017   edc org 123 org
```

I want one row per id. Could you please help.

Thanks

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. We are happy to help you improve code you have written but that doesn't work. Try to solve the problem on your own first, and see what you can come up with.

Comment: Removed the SAS tag, if this is related to SAS please explain how.

Comment: Hello Reeza, I added SAS tag asking if this restructuring can be performed using SAS code. Kindly ignore if thats inappropriate. I will make sure to be more careful while writing the post next time.

Comment: @Brandon Barney, Apologies for the confusion. I needed help in this process but not sure how to proceed. Now that I know, will make sure not to do this again.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions**

1. Your input data resides in an Excel worksheet (I've called it "Input")
2. You want your output data in another Excel worksheet (I've called it "Output")
3. The input data will always be pre-sorted so that records with the same ID are on adjacent rows.
4. For each ID there will be no requirement for more than 2 problems/defects/remedies and no need for more than one Manufacturer or Supplier
5. I think I understood the data in your post. The first dataset appears to be presented as "fixed width" (which seems odd for Excel data). The second is less clear, but based on commonalities with the first dataset, I think I managed to work it out.
6. There may have been other assumptions I was making, these are the ones I was aware of.

**Tab Delimeted Data** (for Pasting to Excel, in a worksheet "Input")

```
ID  Dt  Var1    value1  Var2    Value2
234456  3/14/2017               
234456      problem tap leakage Manufacturer    abc org
234456      defect  LEAKAGE Supplier    xyz org
234456      remedy  repaired        
234456      defct_dt    3/14/2017       
234456      rdy_dt  3/17/2017       
234457  3/21/2017               
234457      problem tap leakage Manufacturer    edc org
234457      problem motor problem       
234457      defect  LEAKAGE     
234457      defect  DEFECTIVE   Supplier    123 org
234457      remedy  repaired        
234457      defct_dt    3/21/2017
```

I decided that my assumptions were plausible and that I would find the problem interesting, so I thought I'd give it a go. Here's what I came up with (no doubt it could be done more efficiently):

**VBA Code**

```
Sub RestructureDate()

    'Input/Output Worksheets
    Dim shtInput As Worksheet
    Dim shtOutput As Worksheet
    Set shtInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    Set shtOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

    'Clear Output Sheet
    shtOutput.Cells.Clear
    'Header Row Output
    shtOutput.Range("A1", "L1") = Array("ID", "Dt", "problem1", "Problem2", "defect1", "defect2", "remedy1", "remedy2", "defect_dt", "remedy_dt", "Manufacturer", "Supplier")
    
    Dim intInputRow As Integer 'Track what row we read from
    Dim intOutputRow As Integer 'Track what row we write to
    Dim PreviousID As String 'ID on the previous input row
    Dim CurrentID As String 'ID on the current input row
    
    'Input Column Structure
    Dim arrayInputRow(6) As String
    
    Dim colInputID As Integer
    Dim colInputDate As Integer
    Dim colInputVar1 As Integer
    Dim colInputValue1 As Integer
    Dim colInputVar2 As Integer
    Dim colInputValue2 As Integer
    colInputID = 0
    colInputDate = 1
    colInputVar1 = 2
    colInputValue1 = 3
    colInputVar2 = 4
    colInputValue2 = 5

    'Output Column Structure
    Dim arrayOutputRow(12) As String
    
    Dim colID As Integer
    Dim colDt As Integer
    Dim colProblem1 As Integer
    Dim colProblem2 As Integer
    Dim colDefect1 As Integer
    Dim colDefect2 As Integer
    Dim colRemedy1 As Integer
    Dim colRemedy2 As Integer
    Dim colDefectDt As Integer
    Dim colRemedyDt As Integer
    Dim colManufacturer As Integer
    Dim colSupplier As Integer
    colID = 0
    colDt = 1
    colProblem1 = 2
    colProblem2 = 3
    colDefect1 = 4
    colDefect2 = 5
    colRemedy1 = 6
    colRemedy2 = 7
    colDefectDt = 8
    colRemedyDt = 9
    colManufacturer = 10
    colSupplier = 11
       
    'Start on the second row of each
    intInputRow = 2
    intOutputRow = 2
    
    'Initialise IDs
    CurrentID = ""
    PreviousID = ""
    
    'We output when we reach the start of the next ID, so need to carry on one row further than you would expect
    'Carry on until "previous" row is blank
    While shtInput.Cells(intInputRow - 1, 1).Text <> ""
        
        'ID Looked at in Previous Loop
        PreviousID = CurrentID
        
        'Read Input Row
        For i = 0 To 5
            arrayInputRow(i) = shtInput.Cells(intInputRow, i + 1).Text
        Next i
        
        'Get ID
        CurrentID = arrayInputRow(colInputID)
       
        'No More Stuff for Previous ID, So Output What We've Got
        If PreviousID <> "" And PreviousID <> CurrentID Then 'No More Stuff
            shtOutput.Range("A" & intOutputRow, "L" & intOutputRow) = arrayOutputRow 'Output
            intOutputRow = intOutputRow + 1 'Move to Next Output Row
        End If
        
        'Set Output ID
        arrayOutputRow(colID) = CurrentID
        'Set Date (only where available)
        If arrayInputRow(colInputDate) <> "" Then arrayOutputRow(colDt) = arrayInputRow(colInputDate)
        
        'Get Other Stuff
        If CurrentID = PreviousID Then    'While it's the same ID
            Select Case arrayInputRow(colInputVar1) 'Check Var1
                Case "problem" 'If Problem
                    If arrayOutputRow(colProblem1) = "" Then 'And Problem1 not used
                        arrayOutputRow(colProblem1) = arrayInputRow(colInputValue1) 'Assign Val1 to Problem1
                    Else
                        arrayOutputRow(colProblem2) = arrayInputRow(colInputValue1) 'Else Assign to Problem2
                    End If
                Case "defect" 'If Defect
                    If arrayOutputRow(colDefect1) = "" Then 'And Defect1 not used
                        arrayOutputRow(colDefect1) = arrayInputRow(colInputValue1) 'Assign Val1 to Defect1
                    Else
                        arrayOutputRow(colDefect2) = arrayInputRow(colInputValue1) 'Else Assign to Defect2
                    End If
                Case "remedy" 'If Remedy
                    If arrayOutputRow(colRemedy1) = "" Then 'And Remedy1 not used
                        arrayOutputRow(colRemedy1) = arrayInputRow(colInputValue1) 'Assign Val1 to Remedy1
                    Else
                        arrayOutputRow(colRemedy2) = arrayInputRow(colInputValue1) 'Else Assign to Remedy2
                    End If
                Case "defct_dt" 'If Defect Date
                    arrayOutputRow(colDefectDt) = arrayInputRow(colInputValue1) 'Assign Val1 to Defect Date
                Case "rdy_dt" 'If Remedy Date
                    arrayOutputRow(colRemedyDt) = arrayInputRow(colInputValue1) 'Assign Val1 to Remendy Date
            End Select
            Select Case arrayInputRow(colInputVar2) 'Check Var2
                Case "Manufacturer" 'If Manufacturer
                    arrayOutputRow(colManufacturer) = arrayInputRow(colInputValue2) 'Assign Val2 to Manufacturer
                Case "Supplier" 'If Supplier
                    arrayOutputRow(colSupplier) = arrayInputRow(colInputValue2) 'Assign Val2 to Supplier
            End Select
        End If
         
        'Next Input Row
        intInputRow = intInputRow + 1
    
    Wend

End Sub
```

**Output**

With the given input, the code above writes the following data to the (pre-existing) worksheet "Output". (Again, this is tab delimeted for pasting to Excel.)

```
ID  Dt  problem1    Problem2    defect1 defect2 remedy1 remedy2 defect_dt   remedy_dt   Manufacturer    Supplier
234456  3/14/2017   tap leakage     LEAKAGE     repaired        3/14/2017   3/17/2017   abc org xyz org
234457  3/21/2017   tap leakage motor problem   LEAKAGE DEFECTIVE   repaired    repaired    3/21/2017   3/17/2017   edc org 123 org
```

Comment: How did you get on @Bhu123 ?

Comment: Hello Steve, I couldn't extract all the values, some are missing. I'm tried making changes to your code which brought in few more values but not all. Got caught up with other work after that so didn't try further. Will try and work on it today and will get back to you. Thanks again!